# Why the $\beta^-$ decay releases $e^-+\nu_e$ and not $\tau$ or $\mu$ generations?

Tags: particle-physics, radiation, neutrinos, bosons, leptons

The $\beta^-$ decay is

\begin{equation}
n \rightarrow p + e^- + \bar\nu_e \tag{1}
\end{equation}

It can be broken down into

\begin{align}
d \rightarrow & \ u + W^-  \tag{2}\\
W^- \rightarrow & \ e^- + \bar \nu_e \tag{3}
\end{align}

Why (3) cannot decay into $(\mu^- + \bar \nu_\mu)$ or $(\tau^- + \bar \nu_\tau)$ ?

Comment: It can and does unless forbidden by energy conservation (which it is in this case).

Comment: @knzhou, Do you mean that the $W^-$ boson, in this case, has not enough energy to produce a heavy lepton? But then, how does it come that the light quark $d$ can decay into a heavy lepton $W^-$?

Comment: The $W$ is a virtual particle.

Comment: The conservation of energy must hold between the intial proton state and the final three-body state. Muon and tau are simply too heavy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Mass of](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Particles/proton.html) neutron

[image: neutron]

mass of proton

[image: proton]

The mass difference 939.6-938.3 is 1.3 MeV and baryon number is conserved anyway, so the neutron can only decay into a proton  after and the excess energy is  1.3 MeV .

The mass of the muon is  107 MeV and the mass of the tau 1777MeV. Energetically only the electron with its small mass of 0.5 MeV is available.